# Remove persisted state from particular MPart

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have perspective with a couple of views (which I want to preserve in workbench.xmi). However there are also editors that I don't want to be persisted. Is there a way to do this? In other words - how to do -clearPersistedState only for particular MPart?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@PreSave` annotation in your LifeCycle class to run a method just before the application model is saved. You can remove the parts you don't want persisted for the model there.

Comment: What is LifeCycle class and how to remove the parts, which I don-t want persisted?

Comment: @ElenaLarina The class specified by the `lifeCycleURI` in the `product` extension point for your e4 application.